# What am I doing wrong in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, scope

Here is my master page code behind:

```
namespace mysite.MasterPages
{
    public partial class Main : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        public bool isLoggedIn;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            isLoggedIn = Request.IsAuthenticated;      // Is the user currently logged in
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my register page code behind:

```
namespace mysite
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (((MasterPage)Page.Master).isLoggedIn)
            {
                Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make the isloggedIn accessible to all pages using that as a master page!  I get errors like:

> Error  2   The name 'isLoggedIn' does not exist in the current context
>
> Error  3   'System.Web.UI.MasterPage' does not contain a definition for 'isLoggedIn' and no extension method 'isLoggedIn' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.MasterPage' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why not just check `Request.IsAuthenticated` on the pages that need it rather than assigning the result of `Request.IsAuthenticated` to another variable?

Comment: I've come from a classic ASP background, and I always assigned more meaningful variable names to things like this, and was taught it's better to assign it to a variable than keep requesting it.

Comment: btw, what kind of authentication do you use? forms (own login page) or basic (default browser login pop-up) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Main.master" %>` to your page markup.

and your `this.Master`'s type becomes `AlphaPack.MasterPages.Main` instead of `System.Web.UI.MasterPage`. So you will be able to access it without cast:

```
 this.Master.IsLoggednIn
```

Currently you need do next:

```
((AlphaPack.MasterPages.Main)this.Master).isLoggednIn
```

And better - create a property. And hold data not in variable but in ViewState (read [Control State vs. View State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1whwt1k7.aspx)):

```
namespace AlphaPack.MasterPages
{
    public partial class Main : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.IsLoggedIn = Request.IsAuthenticated;
        }

        public bool IsLoggedIn
        {
            get { return this.ViewState["isLoggedIn"] as bool? ?? false; }
            set { this.ViewState["isLoggedIn"] = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

And what about code-behind. I recommend to use Web App project, not Web Site project (which is out-of-date)!

Next markup syntax is used. Web app:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyNamespace.MyPage" MasterPageFile="~/MyMaster.master" Title="MyTitile" %>
```

and web site:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MyPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyPage" MasterPageFile="~/MyMaster.master" Title="MyTitile" %>
```

Comment: Thanks, and how would i go about accessing the variable on other pages?  I keep getting errors. (Just so you know you missed a })

Comment: @Tom: Thanks, fixed. See my updated post - second paragraph: use `this.Master.IsLoggednIn` on every page where you put `MasterType`. See more at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
if (((MasterPage)Page.Master).isLoggedIn)
```

Should be

```
if (((mysite.MasterPages.Main)Page.Master).isLoggedIn)
```

You cast `Master` to a `MasterPage` type (which is useless as it is already a `MasterPage`). But `MasterPage` doesn't contain the property `isLoggedIn`. That's why you can't access it.

So, just cast the `Master` property to the right type, in your case `mysite.MasterPages.Main`

Answer (score 0):

Usually one would store such Global 'states' inside a session variable. Are passing it around as a query string parameter?

And why are you not putting the code in the code behind?

**Edit 1:**

Just move this logic:

```
  Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
```

directly into your masterpage:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)      // Is the user currently logged in
        {
            Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
        }
    }
```

If this is the default behaviour you want for all pages that will be using this Master Page.

**Edit 2:**

you said in a comment :

> and how would i go about accessing the
>   variable on other pages?

There are 3 ways I can think of:

- Query String (Per Page Request)
- ViewState (Per Page)
- Session Variable (Available Globally)

Comment: It's from the ASP membership system not query string.

Comment: That's fair enough, but why are you not using the code behind? I suspect your classic ASP background may play a part.

Comment: Yes, I'm just used to having it all on one page!  I still don't quite understand the code behind so will read up on it.

Comment: It's better to configure authentication and authorization in Web.config rather than do manual check on pages

Comment: What?! why the downvote?! abatishchev metions using the viewstate which I've already mentioned yet he is upvoted?!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your are declaring `isLoggedIn` within an inline code-block, so it will only be scoped to within that block.

You'll need to add it as a variable within the code-behind class or within `<script runat="server"></script>` tags, if adding the server-side code inline, i.e. (trimmed down for brevity):

```
<script runat="server">

    public bool IsLoggedIn;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IsLoggedIn = Request.IsAuthenticated;
    }

</script>
```

You could then access the master page in subpages like so:

```
<%
    if (((MasterPage)Page.Master).IsLoggedIn)
    {
    }
%>
```

However, I'm not sure that this is the best way to achieve what you want. I would probably take that logic out of the master page and stick it in a purpose built authentication class or service.

Comment: Thanks, but the variable is logged in doesn't seem to be accessible to the pages that use that master page which is the problem.

Comment: Thanks, it didn't seem to work still, I've changed the question because everyone keeps tellingme to use code behind

Comment: Only Content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains Content controls.

Comment: Don't write code in markup. This is VERY out-of-date style from .NET 1.x. Only if you use ASP.NET MVC and different helpers